# How to remove last row in each group if it is larger in value than the previous row?

Tags: r, dplyr, slice

How would one go about removing the last row by group by column if it has a larger value than its previous column value?

Example:

```
Dataframe:

Column 1    Column 2
Dog            5     
Dog            6
Dog            5
Cat            3
Cat            5
Cat            4
Cat            7
Mule           2
Mule           4
Mule           6
Mule           8
Mouse          4
Mouse          6
Mouse          9
```

I would like it to appear as:

```
Dataframe:

Column 1    Column 2
Dog            5     
Dog            6
Dog            5
Cat            3
Cat            5
Cat            4
Mule           2
Mule           4
Mule           6
Mouse          4
Mouse          6
```

Only the group dog would remain the same in this situation as the last row value in column 2 for that group is smaller than its previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `slice` can be :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Column1) %>%
  slice(if(last(Column2) > nth(Column2, n() - 1)) 
           seq_len(n() - 1) else seq_len(n()))

#  Column1 Column2
#   <fct>     <int>
# 1 Cat           3
# 2 Cat           5
# 3 Cat           4
# 4 Dog           5
# 5 Dog           6
# 6 Dog           5
# 7 Mouse         4
# 8 Mouse         6
# 9 Mule          2
#10 Mule          4
#11 Mule          6
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Column1) %>%
 filter(!(1:n() == max(1:n()) & Column2 > lag(Column2)))

   Column1 Column2
   <chr>     <int>
 1 Dog           5
 2 Dog           6
 3 Dog           5
 4 Cat           3
 5 Cat           5
 6 Cat           4
 7 Mule          2
 8 Mule          4
 9 Mule          6
10 Mouse         4
11 Mouse         6
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a creative answer